# Fill in the blanks for limit superior and limit inferior

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, analysis

I understand when $\{x_n\}$ is bounded, but not quite sure when it is not bounded. I may encounter three cases.

Case 1. Bounded below, not bounded above. In this case, $x_n$ can not converge, and we have $\lim\sup x_n=\infty$

Case 2. Not bounded below, bounded above. In this case, $x_n$ can not converge, and we havewe have $\lim\inf x_n=-\infty$

Case 3. Not bounded below, not bounded above. In this case, $x_n$ can not converge, and we have $\lim\sup x_n=\infty$, $\lim\inf x_n=-\infty$

**If $\lim x_n=\infty$, then it must unbounded above, so $\lim \sup x_n =\infty$, why $\lim \inf x_n=\infty$?**

**Similarly, if $\lim x_n=-\infty$, then it must unbounded below, so $\lim \inf x_n =-\infty$, why $\lim \sup x_n=-\infty$?**

I know a theorem can answer my question, but do not know why. (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Limit_inferior_and_limit_superior)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a proof of $\liminf x_n=\infty$:
$\forall M>0$, since $\lim x_n=\infty$, $\exists N$ s.t. "$n>N \Rightarrow x_n>M$", which implies "$m>N \Rightarrow \inf\{x_i\}_{i>m}\geqslant M$"